# Query MongoDB (via MongooseJS) and save result in Javascript variable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nowjs-sockets

Server-side:

```
var test;

UserModel.findOne({name: 'guest'}, function(err, user) {
    test = user.name;
});

console.log(test);
```

This does not work. The value of "test" is not logged in the console. Moving console.log inside the "UserModel.findOne" callback function works though.

**Question**

How do I get the "user.name" out of my database and into a variable?

**Additional Details**

The reason why I am doing this is because I want to use Mongoose with NowJS like this (grab some detail from MongoDB, send it to client using NowJS etc):

```
nowjs.on('connect', function () { 

    var test;

    UserModel.findOne({name: 'guest'}, function(err, user) {
            test = user.name;
            }); 

    this.now.receiveMessage(test);
});
```

But this is strictly speaking not a question about NowJS.

Comment: On hindsight, I probably shouldn't be doing this. I should be retrieving all the information from the database, putting it into a server-side array/object, and then passing information from that array/object to the client instead of making a database query whenever the user asks for information. However, I am still curious to know how to make this work, for learning reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to put the NowJS call inside the callback:

```
var now = this.now;
UserModel.findOne({name: 'guest'}, function(err, user) {
    now.receiveMessage(user.name);
});
```

Comment: *facepalm* Yes. How could I forgot. Thanks! :)